# How to parse a json from log

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm newbie at Logstash/Kibana (ELK stack) and I dont know how to parse the given json from my log and add "message" and "application" attributes as a field at Kibana.

```
<30>Jan 30 17:52:43 bts/cit-bts-pms-middleware-dev:sprint-01/cit-bts-pms-middleware-dev[862]: {"timestamp":"2017-01-30T17:52:43.713+00:00","message":"Error processing.", "application": "fooApp"}
```

Tks all

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) plugin in order to read **JSON** formatted content. The input could look something like this:

```
input {
    file {
       type => "json"
       path => "/pathto/your.log"
       codec => json
    }
}
```

This should actually do the trick.

**OR** you could still use the [json](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-source) filter which could look something like this. But make sure to remove the **codec** if you're using the below:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

Once the fields are added to every ES record using *logstash*, you should be able to access them in **Kibana**.

Comment: Thanks @Darth_Vader

But my log is partly JSON.
I resolved the problem using REGEX:

<code>
filter {
  grok {
    break_on_match => false
    match => [ "message", "(?<SERVER_TIMESTAMP>(?<=timestamp\":\").*?(?=\",))" ]
    match => [ "message", "(?<MESSAGE>(?<=message\":\").*?(?=\",))" ]
    match => [ "message", "(?<LOG_LEVEL>(?<=level\":\").*?(?=\",))" ]
    match => [ "message", "(?<HOSTNAME>(?<=HOSTNAME\":\").*?(?=\"))" ]
  }
}
</code>

Thanks

Comment: Oh ok. Wasn't aware that your log was partially *json*. Sorry about that.